# Print answer to console in Scilab 6

Tags: console, output, scilab

Older versions of Scilab (5.5.2) would print answers to the console:

```
--> 170957486 / 649294786
 ans  =

    0.2632972  
-->
```

Scilab 6.0.0 does not:

```
--> 170957486 / 649294786
-->
```

Is there a way to change my preferences to the 5.5.2 functionality?  I do not want to use `mprintf` for simple desktop calculator needs.

Comment: My fresh installation of Scilab 6.0.0 on Windows 7 outputs `ans  =  0.2632972`. Something is wrong with your copy of Scilab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SCILAB you can control the behaviour of the console with the mode command.

So try to enter the command `mode(0)`

To better understand look at the help for `mode` command.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know about `mode`.  But my issue has mysteriously resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

And it suddenly works now.  I guess a system restart helped, I didn't change anything else.